# Is there any regular language that is not a context free language?

Tags: regular-language

As the title says, can you guys please explain if there are any Regular languages that are not CFG(context-free-language)?

Answer (score 3):

There is not; the set of regular languages is a proper subset of the set of context free languages (see the [Chomsky hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy#The_hierarchy) of grammars).